# Metacity/Compiz antialias?

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz, metacity, antialiasing

Have Ubuntu developers considered adding antialas to a window manager(metacity) in Ubuntu 11.04? If there is coming Unity and Compiz is needed, why not to add this feature to corners of windows manager?

[image]

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Compiz already has this in the form of the bicubic filter plugin.

Comment: From where I can find it?

Comment: http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compiz-fusion-plugins-extra

Comment: Still, not installed or enabled by default, which seems to be the OP's point.

Comment: I was thinking "installed by default".

Comment: then you need to report a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Emerald solves this problem. It bothered me too so I've done it. Here's a screenshot:

[image: antialiased corner]

Details on how to install it if you're using Natty are in **[this WebUpd8 article](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/get-emerald-to-work-in-ubuntu-1104.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is tracked at these two bug reports:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=345249
https://bugs.launchpad.net/metacity/+bug/606149

From a comment by a Metacity developer in the GNOME bug:

> It should be trivial with any flavor
>   of metacity that has a compositor, and
>   impossible-ish with any flavor that
>   does not.

Also, I believe Roland is incorrect; Compiz's Bicubic Filter plugin doesn't anti-alias window corners.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old but it's the first thing that came up when I was looking to antialias in Compiz, so I'm going to add my answer. I case others are looking in the future/

In the current release I'm using Compiz.reloaded manjaro pkg, there doesn't seem to be a bicubic filter included. I also was not looking to improve the window button AA but the OpenGL effect AA (like Desktop Cube for example).

My way of solving this was to go to the nVidia X Server Settings and to set the OpenGL image quality to High Quality vs the default Quality setting. I also over-rode application AA setting to maxed out AA. It looks alot better now but I have GTX 1080 so your mileage may vary with this solution depending on how powerful your GPU is. If you're gaming on steam, I wouldn't overide application AA settings as that could cause instability with games.

Probably the better solution would be to make a individual 3d profile for compiz but the mechanisms to do this in the nVidia X Server Settings are very un-user friendly and I just don't have the patience to learn it at the moment.